# Стилизация скролла

Tags: css3, html, css

Как можно стилизовать скролл для всех браузеров наподобии контакта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно создать свой скролл. Например, [10 jQuery Custom Scrollbar Plugins](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/).

Comment: http://www.alexilin.ru/styling-scrollbar/
нашел, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал посмотреть в сторону https://github.com/Diokuz/baron

И доклад о библиотечке на FrontTalks в Екатеринбурге:
http://events.yandex.ru/events/yagosti/fronttalks-ekb-jul-2013/talks/983/
http://video.yandex.by/users/fronttalks/view/23#hq